# filter unique parameters from file

Tags: awk, grep

i have file contains urls plus params like following

```
https://example.com/endpoint/?param1=123&param2=1212
https://example.com/endpoint/?param3=123&param1=98989
https://example.com/endpoint/endpoint3/?param2=123
https://example.com/endpoint/endpoint2/?param1=123
https://example.com/endpoint/endpoint2/
https://example.com/endpoint/endpoint5/&quot;//i.example.com/00/s/Nzk5WDEwMjQ=/z/47IAAOSwBu5hXIKF
```

and i need to filter only urls with unique params
the desired output

```
http://example.com/endpoint/?param1=123&param2=1212
https://example.com/endpoint/?param3=123&param1=98989
https://example.com/endpoint/endpoint3/?param2=123
```

i managed to filter only urls with params with grep
`grep -E '(\?[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,9}\=)'`

but i need to filter params in the same time so i tried with awk with the same regex
but it gives error

```
awk '{sub(\?[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,9}\=)} !seen[$0]++'
```

## update

i am sorry for editing the desired output but when i tried the scripts i figured out that their a lot of carbege in my file need to filter too.
i tried @James Brown with some editing and it looks good till the end line it dose not filter it unfortunately

```
awk -F '?|&' '$2&&!a[$2]++'
```

and to be more clear why the that output is good for me
it chosed the 1 st line because it has at least param1
2nd line because it has at least param3
3 line because it has at least param2
the comparison method here is choose just unique parameter whatever it concatenate with others with `&` char or not

Comment: Please look up `sub()` in the awk manual to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited version after the reqs changes some:

```
$ awk -F? '{                   # ? as field delimiter
    split($2,b,/&/)            # split at & to get whats between ? and &
    if(b[1]!=""&&!a[b[1]]++)   # no ? means no $2
        print
}' file
```

Output as expected. Original answer was:

<s>A short one:</s>

```
$ awk -F? '$2&&!a[$2]++' file
```

Explained: Split records at `?` (`-F?`) and if there is a second field (`$2`) and (`&&`) it is unique this far by counting the instances of the parameters in the array `a` (`!a[$2]++`), output it.

Comment: What's the `a` for ?

Comment: @Paolo Updated the explanation but I used `a[]` where OP used `seen[]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm very surprised that globbing doesn't make `?` match any single-char variable names since it's not quoted but I just tried it and that doesn't happen unless you put a blank between `-F` and `?` (on my cygwin system running bash at least). FWIW I'd prefer if this answer was written as `awk -F'?' '(NF==2) && !seen[$2]++' file` for clarity and robustness but it's not a big enough difference for me to write my own answer, hence the upvote and comment instead. Both answers assume no `?` in  the "param" but treat that differently.

Comment: @EdMorton I was a bit surprised myself. I used `-F\?` first but as it appeared to work without the backslash, decided to leave it off for curiosity's sake.

Comment: @JamesBrown Thank you so much for the solution but really sorry for updating output, i tested it with some editing and it works except the last line

Comment: Would this do?: `awk -F? '{split($2,b,/&/);if(b[1]!=""&&!a[b[1]]++)print}' file`?

Comment: thanks @JamesBrown it works very well i just add quote for -F to work, my terminal is terminator in kubuntu so it became ```awk -F '?' '{split($2,b,/&/);if(b[1]!=""&&!a[b[1]]++)print}'```

Comment: @JamesBrown, I am totally confused now, what got changed later on :) please do let me know so that I can add edited answer.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Lol yeah. OP changed the data, mainly this record: `https://example.com/endpoint/endpoint5/&quot;//i.example.com/00/s/Nzk5WDEwMjQ=/z/47IAAOSwBu5hXIKF` which basically has no `?`

Answer (score 5):

***EDIT:*** Following solution may help when query string has `?` as well as `&` present in it and we want to consider both of them for removing duplicates.

```
awk '
/\?/{
  match($0,/\?[^&]*/)
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/&.*/)
  if(!seen[val]++ && !seen[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++){
    print
  }
}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** (Following solution may help when we don't have `&` parameters in query string) With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk 'match($0,/\?.*$/) && !seen[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++' Input_file
```

OR above could be shorten to as follows:(as per Ed sir's suggestions):

```
awk 's=index($0,"?") && !seen[substr($0,s)]++' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` which matches everything from `?` to till end of line value. Then adding an AND condition to it to make sure we get only unique values out of all matched values in all lines.

Answer (score 2):

With `gnu awk`, you could also match the url till the first occurrence of the question mark, and then capture what follows using  your initial pattern for the first parameter `([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,9}=[^&]+)` followed by matching any character except the `&`

Then you can use the `!seen[$0]++` part with the value of capture group 1.

```
awk '
match($0, /https?:\/\/[^?]+\?([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,9}=[^&]+)/, arr) && !seen[arr[1]]++
' file
```

Output

```
https://example.com/endpoint/?param1=123&param2=1212
https://example.com/endpoint/?param3=123&param1=98989
https://example.com/endpoint/endpoint3/?param2=123
```

---

Using `awk` you can check that the string starts with the protocol and contains a question mark.

Then to get the first parameter only, you can split on `?` and `&` and use the second part of the split for `seen`

```
awk '
/^https?:\/\/[^?]*\?/ && split($0, arr, /[?&]/) > 1 && !seen[arr[2]]++
' file
```

Comment: i updated the Q however i tried to reedit the script ```awk 'match($0, /https?:\/\/[^?|^&]+\?+&([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,9}=.*)/, arr) && !seen[arr[1]]++'``` to put OR in comparison but dose not work

Comment: @Emad In that case, you can capture the first parameter, the `=` sign and following any char except `&` in group 1. I have updated the answer.